# Redeploy changes to JSF page(xhtml) when project stage is Production

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, jrebel, hotdeploy

I have set my JSF project stage to **`Production`** to test some stuff that can't be done while running in project stage **`Development`**. Now when I makes changes to jsf pages(ie, the `xhtml`s) the changes aren't visible instantly, even though **`Compile on save`** & **`Deploy on save`** are both enabled. Instead I am forced to do a clean project, rebuild project & redeploy, which certainly takes ages, for a small change in xhtml.

So is there any better way than this(:P) to make the changes visible a bit quicker?

Also I do use JRebel, but it doesn't work with Production mode, even when Production mode has been set it overrides it to Development mode.

Comment: did you generate rebel.xml and deployed it with the app?

Comment: I didn't write that. That was automatically generated for me. I could see that in my project sources right now. if you want to see what it looks like, this is my `rebel.xml` contents below:

Comment: <!-- Generated by the JRebel NetBeans plugin-->
<!-- More info http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/how-to-configure-rebel-xml/ -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.zeroturnaround.com"
             txsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zeroturnaround.com http://www.zeroturnaround.com/alderaan/rebel-2_0.xsd">
 <classpath>
  <dir name="C:\dev\myApp\target\classes"/>

 </classpath>
 <web>
  <link target="/">
   <dir name="C:/dev/myApp/src/main/webapp"/>
  </link>
 </web>  
</application>

Comment: & also to clarify jrebel works fine redeploying code changes in either mode(`Development` or `Production`). Just that it changes `Production` mode to `Development`.

Comment: Yes, JRebel Mojarra plugin sets it to Development mode. Is that a problem? If JRebel is enabled you should disable "Deploy on save", otherwise these features will interfere. If your static resources aren't updated, please ask from JRebel support and send them jrebel.log as described here: http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/learn/sending-log/

Comment: `"JRebel Mojarra plugin sets it to Development mode"` - but I use MyFaces version of JSF & I really want to work in Production mode along with JRebel. I do keep `Deploy on save` disabled. The only issue for me, is forced switching from Prod. mode to dev.  by JRebel which I would love to avoid if possible !?

Comment: It works for MyFaces the same was as for Mojarra. Could you explain what is the issue with enabling development mode automatically?

Comment: I do not want to run my project in Development mode as some of the stuff works properly only when project is  running in Production mode(configured via web.xml). & JRebel doesn't allow me this. So when I need to run my project in Production mode I just need to turn off JRebel through netbeans.

Comment: Per @BalusC 's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960829/whats-the-difference-between-development-and-production-in-myfaces), this is the default behavior in Production mode.